# Android - Show Toast or Other Behaviour when menu button clicked

Tags: android, android-menu

I'd like to be able to show a toast or dialog or other options instead of displaying a menu sometimes, if the menu button is pressed.

I tried this, but of course it doesn't work since onCreateOptionsMenu is called when the Activity is first loaded, not when the Menu key is disabled. Is there any way to do what I'm trying to do?

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
   if (disableMenu())
      Toast.makeText(this, R.string.no_menu_for_you, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

edit: I added the .show() so that people wouldn't focus on that part. This is not what's causing the issue.

Comment: Please do not do this. In part, that is because not all devices have a MENU button. http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2012/01/say-goodbye-to-menu-button.html

Comment: i think u are missing .show(); for showing toast

Comment: Sorry clearly I forgot to put the show, but that wasn't affecting the cause of the issue. Even after adding the .show(), the Toast was displayed when Activity was loaded not when menu button is pressed.

Comment: Also why the -1? Not sure why, just curious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot `.show()` and you should use `onPrepareOptionsMenu`, which is called every time the menu button is pressed.

```
@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
   super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);

   if (disableMenu())
      Toast.makeText(this, R.string.no_menu_for_you, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

   return true;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You forgot to call `show()`:

```
 Toast.makeText(this, R.string.no_menu_for_you, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

**EDIT :**

As you want to `capture the click of a menu buttin`, I guess this will work but I didn't try it:

```
protected boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
     if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MENU) {
         // When Menu Key is pressed
         Toast.makeText(this, R.string.no_menu_for_you, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
         return true;
     }
     return false;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Call `.show()` for showing `Toast` as

```
Toast.makeText(this, R.string.no_menu_for_you, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

instead of

```
Toast.makeText(this, R.string.no_menu_for_you, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
```

Answer (score 1):

you forgot to call show() on your toast.

if this doesn't help try to return true in your onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
and then implement your menu behaviour in onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item).

Comment: Adding true didn't change the fact that the Toast showed up when the Activity was started, not when the menu button was pressed.

Comment: right, that's why you shoul add your toast to the onOptionsSelected - but obviously this won't be called when you menu has no items. Did you try to implement onKeyDown and check for KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MENU ?

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to call **`show()`** method which is required to show the toast.

And to perform any action on menu button,you can use the following way.

Override the `onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)`method like i did  .

```
@Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

        switch (keyCode) 

        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MENU:

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Menu key Pressed", 3000).show();    

            break;  
        }


                return false;
    }
```